# How to get Variable Value from Variable inside Void Function and Use Those Variable to Widget

Tags: flutter

As the title says. so I have a void function like the code below

```
Class Routing{
  // another code

  void _showRouteDetails(here.Route route) {
    int estimatedTravelTimeInSeconds = route.durationInSeconds;
    int lengthInMeters = route.lengthInMeters;

    String minuteDetails = _formatTime(estimatedTravelTimeInSeconds);
    String lengthDetails = _formatLength(lengthInMeters);

    //
    // The Problem is right here
    // I need passing this both variable
    // minutesDetails and lengthDetails to MapScreen class
    // I've trying with code below
    //

    MapScreen(minuteRoutes: minuteDetails, lengthRoutes: lengthDetails);
    _stringReturn("$minuteDetails", '$lengthDetails');
  }

  // another code
}
```

minuteDetails and lengthDetails value is **String**.
I have tried passing both variables into my MapScreen class (StatelessWidget) like the code below

```
 MapScreen(minuteRoutes: minuteDetails, lengthRoutes: lengthDetails);
```

but isn't working. and I tried with

```
_stringReturn("$minuteDetails", '$lengthDetails');
```

The code above is works but I don't know how to use those strings to apply to widgets

My MapScreen class example

```
class MapScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  const MapScreen({
    Key key,
    this.minuteRoutes,
    this.lengthRoutes,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final minuteRoutes, lengthRoutes;

  Future<void> _stringReturn(String min, String length) async {
    print("Test: $min $length");
    var minRoutes = min;
    var lenRoutes = length;
  }
  // the future void work fine for only print the variable
  // but can't call the lenRoutes and minRoutes variable

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
          child: Text(minuteRoutes??"Empty"),
    );
  };
}
```

Any suggestions for this? Thanks before

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to navigate to another screen with some data from previous screen. If this is the case, refer this docs :

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Comment: For full information, I was creating a maps using Here Maps API. I am creating a route or polyline using the void function of another class to get the polyline and the calculate of the route itself so the class is not a state class that contains a widget. It's different from what you suggested